# Detailed description of life of a signal

Tags: operating-system, signals

When a process is waiting for some user input, if ^c is pressed, a signal goes to the OS that kills that process. However the same does not happens when that process is a bash/python interpreter. Also echo ^c prints something on console, so I am assuming that it is a valid unicode character.

So, how does some character inputs gets redirected into the input stream for that process to consume and some gets used as a signal. Where is it decided, what all pre-defined config gets used, and when are those config values set?

Answer (score 1):

You've stumbled into the magical world of the [TTY layer](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

The TL;DR is that there is a big distinction between using a pipe (eg file or other cmd piped to stdin) and having a console attached to stdin. The the console's line-discipline is what hijacks the ^C character (which is just a normal, 8 bit character) and sends a signal to the foreground process group.